# useHistory default for every components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-dom

Why we need to do this in every single component over and over again to use history to navigate our app?

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

I expect to access history object in every single component.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you passed it down to other components as a property?

Comment: @ShamarYarde but at least I don't have to write useHistory every time. My apps have hundred if not thousand of stateless component

Comment: You can make it shorter by writing a custom hook?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the 1st Example: Basic Routing section from the guide in the references below if you just need to navigate to a page.  After setting it up, you could rewrite your HomeButton function as follows:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
    
      return (
        <Link to="/home">
          Go home
        </Link>
      );
    }
```

Another solution you can try is to create a custom button component which changes functionality based on properties passed.  You can try something similar to the following:

*CustomButton.js*

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function CustomButton() {
  let history = useHistory();

  function handleNavigation() {
    history.push(props.location);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    console.log("This function used to handle navigation to the home page.");
  }

  if (props.navigation) {
   return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleNavigation}>
      Go home
    </button>
   );
  } else {
    <button type="button onClick={handleClick}>
      Click
    </button>
  }
}
```

*AnyOtherComponent.js*

```
import CustomButton from "./CustomButton.js"

function AnyOtherComponent() {
 return (
  <div>
   <CustomButton navigation location={"/home"} />
   <CustomButton navigation={false} />
  </div>
 )
}
```

References:

1st Example: Basic Routing. React Training /
React Router. https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start. (Accessed 1 October, 2021).

Comment: I'm not asking how to use the lib, I'm asking how to avoid using useHistory in every single components

Comment: @Fay Chen, I’d have to think about it.  You’re going to have to tell your application when to navigate, so the only solutions I can think of require some sort of navigation code to be called each time.

Comment: @FayChen, I updated my answer which more details on the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use custom hook to reduce the code.

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const useHomeClickHandle = () => {
  let history = useHistory();

  // you should use useCallback here to avoid rerender
  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return handleClick
}

function HomeButton() {
  const handleClick = useHomeHandleClick()
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}

// OR
function HomeButton() {
  // if you don't have any conditional control here
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={useHomeHandleClick()}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not my question. so you have 50 components, do you declare useHistory in those component who need to use history? Don't you feel it's very repetitive

Comment: Do you worry about the performance? If it's, just ignore your feeling because all useHistory use a context that is being used by react-router, and the team already handle performance of this.

Comment: so there's no way to escape this tedious repeatation?

Comment: I like withRouter which is previous solution, we pass the entire history object along with redux, I don't see any performances issue.

Comment: As I understand, you need to use withRouter with what components you want. You still need repeatation, it shorter but it will create a wrapper component inside the high order component. You still can use this as you want. High order component also is a good pattern, I also mixed both ways. Just make the code comfortable to you and your team. 